# ECDSA signing and verification in windows and linux

Tags: linux, windows, cryptoapi, crypto++

This is continuation of my previous post ([Understanding BCryptSignHash output signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992760/understanding-bcryptsignhash-output-signature)).

Let me clearly state my problem:

1. I need to sign a data in windows application level.
2. I need to verify the same in linux application level and windows driver (that i have wrote).

I tried following:

1. Using CryptoAPI, i was able to sign in windows application level and verify in the windows driver. In linux, i tried to use simpleECDSA (http://jonasfj.dk/blog/2007/12/simpleecdsa-a-simple-implementation-of-ecdsa-in-c/) to verify the signature (generated using cryptoAPI). I was able to convert the binary key blobs from cryptoAPI in simpleECDSA but could not interpret the signature.
2. Using Crypto++ library, i was able to sign in windows application level and verify in linux application level but could not use the same to verify in windows driver.

Kindly let me know if there is a library available or a way that i could use the same public/private key and signature across windows application/driver and linux.

Am new to cryptography hence forgive my naiveness.

Thanks,

F

Comment: (Cryptographic) algorithms and their results are completely independent from the operating system or used library.

Comment: @scai - I agree. But the key and signature formats (IEEE P1363/DER/OpenPGP) are different. CryptoAPI exports keys as binary blobs. My doubt is whether there is a common format between windows and linux.

Comment: DER and PEM are very common formats.

Comment: My main problem is converting the binary blobs to DER certificates that i can use with crypto++ in linux. If i can do that i believe i will be able to solve this issue. Is there a call in Crypto++ to convert the binary blob to DER certificate? Or is there a CryptoAPI call that exports key in DER format?

Comment: "My main problem is converting the binary blobs to DER certificates..." - Crypto++ does *not* produce certificates. Only public keys and private keys.

Comment: Yes my mistake. I have created public and private keys which i guess is in DER format. `ECDSA<ECP, SHA512>::PrivateKey privKey; privKey.Initialize( prng, ASN1::secp256r1() );` I used this code to generate private key and wrote to a file. Now i want to import this key in cryptoAPI. If someone can point to cryptoAPI call or set of calls that will do this, it would be helpful.

Comment: "... which i guess is in DER format." - See [Keys and Formats](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats) from the Crypto++ wiki. [Cryptographic Interoperability: Keys](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25487/Cryptographic-Interoperability-Keys) might also be helpful. Sorry I can't answer more. I work with OpenSSL and Crypto++. I know nothing about `cryptoAPI` or the library that provides it.

Comment: Also, be careful with statements like "let me know if there is a library available". That could move your question into "Off Topic" because you're asking to find you a favorite library (see the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)). I personally don't care, but others will move to close the question. Its better to ask directed, closed-ended questions. For example, you should probably keep drilling on the `cryptoAPI` since that seems to be your pain point (but you provide almost no details about it or how you are using it).

Comment: @noloader: Thanks a lot for your help (both technical and how to ask question). I was able to solve the problem by playing around with keys. CryptoAPI's binary blob contains the public point and the private exponent in big-endian format. I extracted the above info from crypto++ generated key and generated the binary blob. With the the crypto++ generated key, i signed a data and i was able to verify the same with the binary blob (that i generated) in cryptoapi. Hence now, i use crypto++ in windows/linux application level and use cryptoAPI in windows driver.

Comment: Referenced links: CryptoAPI binary blob format(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and crypto++ key contents (http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme).

Comment: I wrote some code to convert DER to the blob format and I posted it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618755/verify-bouncycastle-ecdsa-signature-with-net-libraries-ecdsacng/34770707 You can also find other useful information here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25590/Cryptographic-Interoperability-Digital-Signatures I did write some code to convert to the DER format, but I have not tested it and am hesitant to post it because of that. This claims to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490135/creating-asn1-encoded-signature-in-c-sharp-to-send-to-java